# Jquery Cycle / Open other page with other cycle plugin in a specific slide

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

I wonder if its possible to open a new **page.html** that contains a cycle plugin and go to an specific slide. I mean, from **page1.html** to **page2.html** and make the plugin start for example in **slide 6**.

I dont know so much JS, but here is the code im trying to use:

$(function() {
    $('#cycle_images').cycle({ 
        timeout: 0, 
        speed: 300,
    fx: 'scrollVert',
        startingSlide: 0 
    });

```
$('#button').click(function() {
window.location = 'page2.html' 
    $('#cycle_images').cycle(6); 
    return false;
});
```

});

Thanks a lot !! And sorry for my bad english:(

Comment: page one -  window.location = 'page2.html#6' , Second page write ur script if url[somehting]#6  cycle go to 6

Comment: Hi!Thanks a lot for youe answer, im really not sure how to put the code of the second page, Something like this??

<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.location.href == "page2.html"){
$('#rotating-item-wrapper').cycle(4);
}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Page one button id

```
<a href="pagetwo.html#2" target="_blank">Click me</a>
```

second page [slider page]

code like this [Up date with your class name]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var urlNo = location.hash.split('#')[1]
   alert(urlNo);


    $('#banner').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 500,
        timeout: 5000,
        next: '#next',
        prev: '#previous',
        pause: 1
    });

    if ( urlNo == urlNo ){
    $('#banner').cycle(urlNo); 
    return false; 
    }


});
```

[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/HuNfz/170/)

Comment: Thanks again, i really appreciate it, but i cannot make it work, This is how i did it: 

PAGE1:
<a href="page2.html#6">Click me</a>

PAGE2:
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   var urlNo = location.hash.split('#')[4]     
    
    $('#rotating-item-wrapper').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 500,
        timeout: 5000,
        next: '#next',
        prev: '#previous',
    });
    
    if ( urlNo == urlNo ){
    $('#rotating-item-wrapper').cycle(urlNo); 
    return false; 
    } 
});
</script>

Comment: urlNo = location.hash.split('#')[4] Its wrong , Use my code

Comment: I update with your code, but nothing, it always send me to the first slide :(

Comment: Hi Again! Maybe this can help to explain better what im trying to do:

In this link you can see a little demo:

<http://www.contactarte.com.pe/test/page1.html

I just want that if you click for example slide4 button, the next page2 will load starting with slide4

Thanks again !!

Comment: Where is script ? on second page ?

Comment: You missed #4 for button  ,   href="page2.html#4"

Comment: Hi there! I update the link with your code but still not working, can you take a look please?

[link]http://www.contactarte.com.pe/test/page1.html

Thanks a lot !